# How To Use authenticate_or_request_with_http_token With Grape?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, ruby-grape, grape-api

how can I implement authenticate_or_request_with_http_token in grape API. Below is my code :

```
module Articles 
    class ArticleData < Grape::API
        include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods
     #   http_basic do |email, password|
        #   user = User.find_by_email(email)
        #   user && user.valid_password?(password)
        # end

        before do
            error!("401 Unauthorized", 401) unless authenticated
        end

        helpers do
            def authenticated
                 authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
                    apiKey = ApiKey.where(auth_token: token).first
                     #ApiKey.exists?(access_token: token)
                 end
            end
        end

        resource :article_data do

            desc "Return all article data"
            get do
                Article.all
            end

            desc "create a new article"
            ## This takes care of parameter validation
            params do
                requires :title, type: String
                requires :author, type: String
                #requires :content, type: Text
            end

            #This takes care of creating article
            post do
                Article.create!({
                    title:params[:title],
                    content:params[:content],
                    author:params[:author],
                    user_id:params[:user_id],
                    image_url:params[:image_url]
                })
            end

            desc "update article"
            # this takes care of parameter validation
            params do
                requires :image_url, type: String
            end

            put ':id' do
                Article.find(params[:id]).update({
                    content:params[:content],
                    image_url:params[:image_url]
                })
            end

            desc "delete article by id"
            # this takes care of parameter validation
            params do 
                requires :id, type: String
            end

            delete ':id' do
                Article.find(params[:id]).destroy!
            end

        end

    end
end
```

I got this error **NoMethodError (undefined method `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token' for #):** when I run the curl command : curl http://localhost:3000/api/v1/article_data.json. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: show your application controller.